# How to cite an article with an article number (instead of page range)

Tags: soft-question, journals, mathematical-writing, citations, mathscinet

I am curious to know what is the standard way (in AMS style) to cite a journal article that has an article number and/or a page range.

For instance, here is a BibTeX entry from MathSciNet of an article published in Proceedings A:

```
@article {MR4212412,
    AUTHOR = {Kallosh, Renata},
     TITLE = {M-theory, black holes and cosmology},
   JOURNAL = {Proc. A.},
  FJOURNAL = {Proceedings A},
    VOLUME = {477},
      YEAR = {2021},
    NUMBER = {2245},
     PAGES = {20200786, 15},
      ISSN = {1364-5021},
   MRCLASS = {83E30 (83C57 83E50)},
  MRNUMBER = {4212412},
       DOI = {10.1098/rspa.2020.0786},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.2020.0786}.
}
```

As you can see, the `PAGES` field contains both the article number `20200786` as well as the number of pages `15`. On the other hand, it seems more logical to me to just write `1--15`, because the article in question does have page numbers, and they run from 1 to 15. (The latter approach is in accordance with APA style; see [here](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/05/how-to-cite-an-article-with-an-article-number-instead-of-a-page-range.html).)

In other cases, like articles published in Physical Review Letters (which is not covered by MathSciNet), an article has a six-digit number (e.g., 238104) and the $n$th page is identified by 238104-$n$.

How would you cite these articles? The AMS Style Guide completely ignores the issue.

EDIT. Since I posted the question, the format of the BibTeX entry of an article with an article number has changed in MathSciNet. The number itself is now preceded by the expression "Paper no.". For instance, the `PAGES` field of the given Proceedings A article now reads as follows:

```
PAGES = {Paper No. 20200786, 15}
```

Comment: My advice is to follow the MathSciNet style.

Comment: There is probably not much to worry about here. If your article is accepted, then the publisher will format the reference in whatever way they want, anyhow.

Comment: @Iosif No, please. This advice leads to all sorts of problems with the way references are listed. Many journals just take whatever the authors send and publish it without careful checking.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : My impression has been different, actually rather to the opposite. Oftentimes, they would format references in ways I would not. However, if what you say is the case, then it is actually another argument to suggest that the authors format the references any way they prefer -- whether the publisher will then reformat them or not.

Comment: Personally, I would add "pp." to the end of the pages field there. Otherwise your reader may rightly have no idea what the number means when they see it in your bibliography.

Comment: I want to voice my objection to closing this question.  Unfortunately, more and more journals are switching to this format, in particular, Elsevier has already switched some of its mathematics journals, so mathematicians have better figure out a good way to cite these articles.

Comment: I'd change it to PAGES = {20200786 (15 pages)},

Comment: The MathSciNet format is wrong, simply because 20200786 is *not a page number*. It may happen to work in a particular style the AMS is presumably using, but a different BibTeX style may well format it as the nonsense “pp. 20200786, 15” (or “pp. paper No. 20200786, 15” after the update). The only reliable way to include an article number in BibTeX is to put it in a NOTE field. The *proper* way is to put it in an ARTICLENUMBER field or some such; this of course requires modifying the style file to make it work (but the MathSciNet output already contains many such nonstandard fields).

Comment: I'm a production editor for ALCO (https://alco.centre-mersenne.org/), and this is an issue (no pun intended!) that comes up a lot when copy-editing articles for the journal. What we would do for your example is not use the PAGES tag at all; instead we would include EID = {20200786} and PAGETOTAL={15}. But this is for our particular style sheet; I do not know if these tags work with, e.g., AMS style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to format this bibliographic reference as follows:

Renata Kallosh.
M-theory, black holes and cosmology.
Proceedings of the Royal Society A 20200786 (2021).
[doi:10.1098/rspa.2020.0786](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.2020.0786),
[arXiv:2009.11339](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.11339).

**Rationale**: The purpose of a bibliographic reference is
to give the reader a very rough idea what the article is about and when it was written and to allow the reader locate the full text of the article as fast as possible.

The former purpose is achieved by including the title, author, and year.

The latter purpose is achieved through a multitude of ways.

If the article is accessed online, through a format like PDF or HTML,
then the DOI link at the end of the reference instantly takes the reader
to the referenced article.

If the article is printed on paper, and the reader wants to locate
the referenced article online, then my impression
is that by far the most common method is to supply a search engine with the last name and title of the paper.

This method almost always succeeds, but occasionally it is necessary
to include precise and unambiguous information,
especially if the journal is obscure and/or the article was published
a long time ago.
That's why the journal name and article number should be included, just in case.

I would suggest not to include the volume, issue, or page numbers,
since these are completely redundant in presence of an article number and including four different numbers makes it confusing which one should be used.

I would also not worry about potentially confusing this number with some other
information.
Whether we like it or not, this format will become increasingly more common, and soon everybody will be
aware that a number with more than 4 digits in a bibliographic
reference must be the article number.

I also recommend against abbreviating authors' names or journal names.
Not abbreviating authors' names makes it easier to search online
for a particular author.  This is especially important
for some very common last names, e.g., MathSciNet currently lists 20026 authors with the last name Wang.

Not abbreviating journal names makes easier to search for really obscure
journals.  (The interlibrary loan service at my university,
for example, requires unabbreviated journal names.)

Of course, a particular journal can (and often will) change
the format of bibliographic reference to suit its style.
However, many journals will preserve your DOI and arXiv hyperlinks if you include them.
Additionally, an important factor to keep in mind is that
if your paper is available on arXiv, more than 90% of downloads
of your paper will be from arXiv and not from the publisher's website.
(If you know a source with precise data, please indicate it in the comments.)
Accordingly, the overwhelming majority of the readers
will see the references the way the author formats them,
whereas the publisher's version will only be seen by a minority.

Comment: If the only purpose of a bibliography entry was to allow the reader to find the paper, surely you could also omit the author names.

But that is not the only purpose of a bibliography entry. I, for one, frequently like to know roughly how long a paper is, without going to the effort of actually looking it up, which is why I recommend PAGES = {20200786, 15 pp.} above.

Comment: @VinceVatter: You seem to be objecting to a straw man.  I indicated two different purposes, only one of which is to locate the paper.  The other purpose definitely requires the author names.

Comment: But then you removed the page count.

Comment: @VinceVatter: Do you also include page counts for books that you cite in your papers?  Does it really matter (enough to bother including it in the bibliography) that a particular cited result is proved in a 25-page paper as opposed to a 37-page paper?

Comment: The question was how to cite papers without page numbers. My suggestion is to keep the page count, because that information would otherwise not be in the bibliography. Your suggestion leads to a scenario where a reader can deduce the page count of article if and only if the journal has page numbers.

Comment: @VinceVatter: But what would be the purpose of including the page count?  How do you envision using it?

Comment: I think there are two frameworks from which to approach this question. One is to rethink everything about the bibliography, as your answer does. The other is to just follow the principle that a reference to an article in a journal without page numbers should contain the same information as a reference to an article in a journal with page numbers. If a journal has page numbers, you can see from the bibliography how long the paper is. Ergo if a journal doesn't have page numbers, you should include how long the paper is.

Comment: @VinceVatter: I see your point.  However, my personal impression is that the overwhelming number of citations to articles that are only on arXiv, articles that are accepted but not yet published in a journal, and articles that have already been published online (and, say, assigned a DOI number) but not yet in print, do not include the number of pages in the reference.  My inference from this is that most authors do not find such information useful, which is why they do not include it in the references.  My own proposed format was structured in accordance with this observation.

Comment: I would guess that the reason that people don't include number of pages when they cite arXiv papers is that the number of pages will most likely change. For a published paper, it will not change. I guess there is another principle at work here: your bibliography should not contain information that is likely to become incorrect.